# Handling Win+Shift+Arrow to move window between monitors

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently investigating why the Win+Shift+Arrow shortcut isn't working for my application, but can't seem to get any events or find any information on the functionality.

Essentially, I should be able to hit Win+Shift+Left to move the window to monitor left of the one the application is currently running on. (Or the right-most monitor, if the current monitor is left-most)

Based on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28VS.85%29.aspx), I should get a WM_GETMINMAXINFO event before this occurs, however this is never sent for the shortcut. Is there anything I need to implement to support the functionality?

Comment: Which version of the OS, what other software are you running that could swallow the keystroke?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything for your program to support that functionality. It should "just work," unless your application is somehow intercepting those key events.